# C# - Microsoft word interop find text replace with picture

Tags: c#, image, text, replace, office-interop

How do I find text in a word document and replace the text with a picture? I know how to replace text with text, but is there anyway to replace text with picture?

Comment: What code do you have for replacing text with text?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a valid `Word.Range` object for the text you want to replace then you can use `InlineShapes.AddPicture()`.

For example:

```
// Get the Range for the text you want to replace, which you claim to be able to do already.
Word.Range selectedText = GetTextToReplace();

// Clear the existing text, otherwise the image will just be appended after the text.
selectedText.Text = "";

// Insert the image.
selecetdText.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagePath, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing);
```